# Babylon.js, making turrets face the middle of the field?

Tags: javascript, babylonjs

I am getting started with Babylon.js and am getting stuck.  I have this code to create boxes and add cylinders to them.  When clicked, bullets fire out from the cylinder.

I've added a playground link here:  https://playground.babylonjs.com/#ELP0A5#2

I'm placing the turrets on the field and attempting to rotate them all to face each other.  With my code today, the first and final turret are place perfectly.

However, I cannot get the middle two turrets to face the right direction.  I feel I need to flip the starting X for turret 1 and both the x and Y for turret two, but the syntax is alluding me!

[image]

Can anyone help me aim my little boxes?

```
 var canvas = document.getElementById('renderCanvas');
    canvas.width = 800; // Set the width of the canvas
    canvas.height = 600; // Set the height of the canvas
    var engine = new BABYLON.Engine(canvas, true);

    var createScene = function () {
        var scene = new BABYLON.Scene(engine);
        scene.enablePhysics();

        // Create camera
        var camera = new BABYLON.ArcRotateCamera('camera', Math.PI / 2, Math.PI / 4, 5, new BABYLON.Vector3(0, 0, 0), scene);
        camera.attachControl(canvas, true);

        var light = new BABYLON.HemisphericLight("light", new BABYLON.Vector3(0, 1, 0), scene);
        light.intensity = 0.7;
        console.log("Adding a big light!");

        var light0 = new BABYLON.PointLight("Omni0", new BABYLON.Vector3(1, 10, 1), scene);
        light0.diffuse = new BABYLON.Color3(1, 0, 0);
        light0.specular = new BABYLON.Color3(1, 1, 1);
        console.log("Adding a light!");

        // Create turrets old
        // var turretColors = [new BABYLON.Color3(1, 0, 0), new BABYLON.Color3(0, 1, 0), new BABYLON.Color3(0, 0, 1), new BABYLON.Color3(1, 1, 0), new BABYLON.Color3(1, 0, 1), new BABYLON.Color3(0, 1, 1)]; var turrets = [];

       
       // Create turrets
var turretColors = [
    new BABYLON.Color3(1, 0, 0),
    new BABYLON.Color3(0, 1, 0),
    new BABYLON.Color3(0, 0, 1),
    new BABYLON.Color3(1, 1, 0)
  ];

  var turrets = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    var turret = BABYLON.MeshBuilder.CreateBox('turret' + i, { size: 0.5 }, scene);
    turret.position.x = (i % 2 === 0) ? -2 : 2;
    turret.position.z = (i < 2) ? -2 : 2;
    turret.material = new BABYLON.StandardMaterial('turretMat' + i, scene);
    turret.id = "turret" + i;
    console.log("creating turret of " + turretColors[i] + " color");
    // Set bright colors for turrets
    turret.material.diffuseColor = turretColors[i];

    // Set the initial rotation angles to make turrets face each other
    turret.rotation.y = (i % 2 === 0) ? Math.PI : 0;

    var cylinder = BABYLON.MeshBuilder.CreateCylinder('cylinder' + i, { height: 0.8, diameter: 0.2 }, scene);
    cylinder.material = new BABYLON.StandardMaterial('cylinderMat' + i, scene);
    cylinder.material.diffuseColor = new BABYLON.Color3(0, 1, 1); // Set the color of the cylinder

    // Position the cylinder perpendicular to the box and aligned with the direction of the box
    cylinder.position.y = 0.25; // Adjust the position along the local Y-axis
    cylinder.position.z = 0.25; // Adjust the position along the local Y-axis
    cylinder.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2; // Align with the direction of the box
    cylinder.parent = turret; // Make the cylinder a child of the box
    // if (i === 1 || i === 2) {
    //     turret.rotation.y += Math.PI * .5;
    //   }

    if (i===2){
        turret.rotation.y -= Math.PI;
    }

    if (i === 3) {
      // Flip direction on both axes for turret 3
      turret.rotation.x = Math.PI;
      turret.rotation.z = Math.PI;
    }

    // Add oscillation animation
    var oscillationAnimation = new BABYLON.Animation('oscillationAnimation', 'rotation.y', 30, BABYLON.Animation.ANIMATIONTYPE_FLOAT, BABYLON.Animation.ANIMATIONLOOPMODE_CYCLE);
    var oscillationKeys = [];
    oscillationKeys.push({ frame: 0, value: 0 });
    oscillationKeys.push({ frame: 15, value: Math.PI / 2 });
    oscillationKeys.push({ frame: 30, value: 0 });
    oscillationAnimation.setKeys(oscillationKeys);
    turret.animations = [oscillationAnimation];
    scene.beginAnimation(turret, 0, 30, true);

    turrets.push(turret);
  }
```